# Share Files between Apps on the same iPad (Without iCloud)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have two iPad apps, one which downloads data from a server and stores it on the iPad and another one (the main app) which uses the data later.
(It would make sense to combine the two but it's a client requirement)

But I see no way to share the data between the two apps.
I have heard there are ways to do it using:

- Custom URL Schemes
- Document Support on iPad Devices
- UIPasteboard

But I cannot find any thing explaining how to use any of these effectively.
Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Just to clarify:

1. It is an iPad only app
2. Both apps will not run at the same time
3. Basically I need to access the documents or caches folder of one app from another
4. Using iCloud or any other third part service is not possible
5. It would be great if I could make the downloader app into a sort of configuration page for the main app (if it is even possible)

So keeping these in mind which one would be the most suitable?

Comment: Search more, any of them could do what you want

Comment: I am looking for more information on "Document Support on iPad Devices". IT sounds like the perfect solution. But I can't seem to get any information on it.

Comment: did you check the link blindman457 posted? the one after the EDIT

Comment: I am currently working on a solution based on blindman's answer (using custom url schemes and custom UIPasteboard) but this requires the user to launch one application from another. This is not exactly suitable for my application. Hence i was asking about " Document Support on iPad Devices" . I can't find any information on it.

Comment: I think the Document Support is just for sharing with the pc through iTunes, I don't think it's possible what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link at github](https://github.com/marekbell/iOS-File-Browser) may be useful... Looks like someone has already made a file manager, using these elements you may be able to do what you are looking for.  But as far as I know, your app is extremely sandboxed and does not really interact with other apps/the file system very much at all (Apple is very limiting that way)

**EDIT**

[this post](http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/) seems to have the explanations of local data sharing methods you were looking for.  None of the methods in this post requires any connectivity, just a device and 2 apps :) Good luck!